# How to fetch field from MySQL query result in bash

Tags: mysql, bash

I would like to get only the value of a MySQL query result in a bash script. For example the running the following command:

```
mysql -uroot -ppwd -e "SELECT id FROM nagios.host WHERE name='$host'"
```

returns:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 0  |
+----+
```

How can I fetch the value returned in my bash script?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Use `-s` and `-N`:

```
> id=`mysql -uroot -ppwd -s -N -e "SELECT id FROM nagios.host WHERE name='$host'"`
> echo $id
0
```

From [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/mysql-command-options.html):

> --silent, -s
>
> ```
>    Silent mode. Produce less output. This option can be given multiple
>    times to produce less and less output.
>
>    This option results in nontabular output format and escaping of
>    special characters. Escaping may be disabled by using raw mode; see
>    the description for the --raw option.
> ```
>
> --skip-column-names, -N
>
> ```
>    Do not write column names in results.
> ```

**EDIT**

Looks like `-ss` works as well and much easier to remember.

Comment: Similar to @corgi's answer, multiple columns will be tab delimited.

Comment: To avoid getting errors as output, redirect stderr:
`id=\`mysql -uroot -ppwd -ss -e "SELECT id FROM nagios.host WHERE name='$host'" 2> /dev/null\``

Comment: How to fetch multiple columns?

Comment: @Deckard $ set `mysql -uroot -ppwd -ss -e "SELECT 'a','b'`. Then the value of $1 should be "a" and $2 "b".

Answer (score 12):

Even More Compact:

```
id=$(mysql -uroot -ppwd -se "SELECT id FROM nagios.host WHERE name=$host");
echo $id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
mysql -B --column-names=0 -uroot -ppwd -e "SELECT id FROM nagios.host WHERE name='$host'"
```

-B will print results using tab as the column separator and

--column-names=0 will disable the headers.

Comment: thank you, this is helpful for creating a bash option list.

Comment: This is very useful as it shows how to return the result "without" the column name which is really useful when you are trying to set a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solutions but always received empty response.

In my case the solution was:

```
#!/bin/sh

FIELDVALUE=$(mysql -ss -N -e "SELECT field FROM db.table where fieldwhere = '$2'")

echo $FIELDVALUE
```