# Assigning result of a select query to a variable in shell script

Tags: sql, shell

I am trying to execute select query and store the result in a variable in shell script. Below is the script

```
   mysql="mysql -h localhost -u root"
   db="testdb";
   echo "Select Name from Details"|${mysql} ${db};
```

The above statement gets executed with the column 'Name' getting printed with its value. But when i try to assign the result like below

```
   var = `"Select Name from Details"|${mysql} ${db};`
   echo $var

   or

   var = $("Select Name from Details"|${mysql} ${db};)
   echo $var
```

I get the below error 'var: not found'. Where am i going wrong in trying to assign the result of the query to the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   var=`echo "Select Name from Details"|${mysql} ${db};`
   echo $var
```

There should not be any space between the variable name and `=`. The shell else interprets the variable name to be a command/executable. And hence the error!

Comment: i tried removing the space and executing but it throws an error of "Select Name from Details Not Found". Why does it occur?

Comment: try my updated answer please. Added `echo` to the String

Comment: @Maheswaren: I get the result as 'Name aarish'. How do i parse it so as to retrieve the name alone?

Comment: try the `-ss` option to turn off the headers.

Comment: Sorry @aarish , Not Sure abt turning headers off in mysql. In oracle it is simple.!

Comment: @Maheswaren: okay no probs.. but i found the question similar to mine in the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558867/how-to-fetch-field-from-mysql-query-result-in-bash

Comment: mysql="mysql -h $cls_ip -u root -s -N". This ' -s -N' tags help me retrieve only the values in mysql