# Assigning the output of a BQ query to variable

Tags: mysql, shell, google-bigquery

I am trying to query the total count of a partition in BigQuery and store the result in a mysql table. I am doing this for monitoring purpose.

```
#!/bin/sh
query1="bq query --format=csv 'SELECT COUNT(1) as Count FROM [dataset.tablename] WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP(\"$date\")'"
eval result=\$\($query1\)
echo "$result"

bq_insertquery="insert into <<table>>(<<column>>) values(${result})"
echo $bq_insertquery | mysql -u root -p <<dbname>>
```

Am getting error while insertion in mysql table. This is probably because the variable $result includes both the header and the value, i.e.

Variable $result holds: value with the header

Looks like myquery will be able to insert data, if i get only the value.
How should i assign only value to a shell variable, and use it thereafter ?

Edit: Any sql output contains column_name and values. The variable i assigned to store the value from BigQuery also contains both, i.e. column_name and value. I am looking for something which would be helpfull in extracting only value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable to the output from a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)

Comment: @I0b0 i have updated the question

Comment: It's still a duplicate. Have a look at the linked question. Extracting only the value is a completely separate issue solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558867/how-to-fetch-field-from-mysql-query-result-in-bash)

Comment: I checked the approaches given, including command substitution, none of it helps in extracting the value only. This is the main issue i am facing
"Extracting only the value is a completely separate issue".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add the `--quiet` flag (ignore status updates while jobs are running), and pipe it to `awk`:

```
query1="bq query --quiet --format=csv 'SELECT COUNT(1) as Count FROM [dataset.tablename] WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP(\"$date\")' | awk '{if(NR>1)print}'"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use `jq` command to parse the json output from the query. Before that you need to install `jq` command first. Here is the way to put count into a

```
result=$(echo -e "select 1 as col" | bq query --nouse_legacy_sql --format=json)
echo $result
```

it shows the output `[{"col":"1"}]`. Now it's time to use `jq` command to get final output.

```
count=$(echo $count | jq '.[0]' | jq '.col')
echo $count
```

In One line:

```
count=$(echo $(echo -e "select 1 as col" | bq query --nouse_legacy_sql --format=json) | jq '.[0]' | jq '.col')
```